# Error when specifying the SDK folder

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have just installed Titanium Appcelerator, and when trying to specify the SDK folder I receive the following error:

Please guide me to solve this [image]problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in your directory, rename it, from this:

> D:\ANDROID SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64

To this and see if that works:

> D:\ANDROIDSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64

Comment: i did as u suggested, but still having the same problem

Comment: Have you installed the newest versions of the SDK with the SDK manager?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `platforms` directory is not there at the given path.

My Android sdk home has the below folder structure:

[image: Folder structure of android sdk home]